# What does top -H -p <JVMprocessid> gives? java thread count?

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I am running a multi-threaded java application. The application is running near 150 threads.
I wanted to check the detailed memory usage of those thread.
When I executed top -H -p  i got only 14 as count where as I am running near 150 thread in application.
This sounds very confusing. SO what the number I am getting using top command?

Can anyone please help me to understand such behaviour?

Comment: you mean `-H` (`-h` is help, `-H` is threads)? And where did you get that number from?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. its top -H -p <jvmprocessid> .   That command gave me the number

Comment: Your command seems to work just fine for me, have you tried to have a look with sth like `jvisualvm` or `jstack` which can display all active java threads? Just 14 means there is almost nothing running, because finalizer, gc, .. thread count of an empty application are in that region already.

Comment: I am creating connection pool myself with having strong reference to each created thread. So threads can not get garbage collected. But whay only 14 number it is returning instead of 150?

Comment: the `Thread` class is not the same as a running thread. It's just an interface to control threads. If your threads are done, they don't appear anymore in any thread count, the only thing that may exist is that object that you keep alive but it's no different from any other object in memory at that point.

Comment: I am creating a threadpool which will last till the application is not been terminated

Comment: Thread pools (`Executors.new???`) do not create threads until they are needed and some of them also kill them once there is no more need for them (the cached variety)

Answer (score 0):

On linux there will be one native thread per jvm thread. JVM threads include both application threads and internal threads that the JVM uses for GC and other housekeeping. There are usually 4-10 of these, though it varies by hardware, configuration, etc.

top -H will be an accurate reflection of the number of jvm threads, and the number of application threads will be jvm threads - housekeeping threads.

The specification of 150 application threads is likely being interpreted as a maximum, not a fixed amount.